# Angular 4 - Internalization - Select lang

Tags: angular

I am using angular i18n for to have multiples languages in my web.

Now, my web has two language: Spanish and English.

The multiple language working ok using commands:

```
ng serve
```

By default is in english. Will show: Search Criteria

```
ng serve --aot --locale es --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.es.xlf --missing-translation error
```

or

```
ng serve --aot \
           --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.es.xlf \
           --locale=es \
           --i18n-format=xlf
```

It launchs the application in spanish. Will show: Criterios de Busqueda

But now, I need to select the language from my web site.

```
<div class="text-right divLang"><a href="">Español</a> | <a href="">English</a></div>
```

This is my traslate template (for the moment is my only one template):

```
messages.es.xlf
```

Example of file content messages.es.xlf:

```
<trans-unit id="main_searchTitle" datatype="html">
<source>Search Criteria</source>
<target>Criterios de Busqueda</target>
<context-group purpose="location">
  <context context-type="sourcefile">C:/develop/angular/multi/multi.component.ts</context>
  <context context-type="linenumber">3</context>
</context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

I am not using systemsjs, i am using webpack.

How could do it?

Comment: I am revising this web https://plnkr.co/edit/JyE4l4TjEruuPsrbanmK?p=preview, I think the solution is here.

Comment: I am not use the file: i18n.provider.ts, I will follow searching.

Comment: Can I to select the language from my web unused the file i18n.provider.ts?, Using commands, is not necesary to have this file.